# Samba unable to write when mounting from Linux

Tags: linux, mount, samba

I'm having some weird issues with samba. Somehow I'm not able to write to the mounted share from Linux over VPN but it works without problems when mounting from Windows hosts on the same local network.

This is how I mount the share:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=devbox //10.3.10.65/shop mnt/
```

> /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
wins server = 10.3.10.210
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 1
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
passdb backend = smbpasswd:/etc/samba/smbpasswd
unix password sync = no

[shop]
   comment = Shop
   path = /var/www/shop
   writable = yes
   browsable = yes
   valid users = devbox
   guest ok = no
   force user = www-data
   force group = www-data
   read only = no
   create mask = 0660
   directory mask = 0775
```

> /var/www/shops

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1015 Mar 30 12:37 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 30 12:37 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1280 Apr 19 12:47 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 45242 Apr 19 12:47 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 30 12:42 config
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   648 Mar 30 12:37 index.php
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  4096 Apr  4 06:13 logs
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   880 Mar 31 07:37 npm-debug.log
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1202 Mar 30 12:37 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 30 12:37 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  8 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 30 12:37 src
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 30 12:37 tests
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 31 07:43 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 16 www-data www-data  4096 Apr 19 12:47 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 Apr 20 14:41 webroot
```

I have no idea what's going on. I've tried to force the mount with `-o uid=33 -o gid=33` and chmodded permissions both in smb.conf and on the files. Nothing helps; what is causing this?

Could it have something to do with the VPN? I've pointed the wins&hostname to the correct ip in my /etc/hosts file, but didn't seem that it had anything to do with that.

I booted up Windows and was able to mount it over OpenVPN and perform writes, so it must have something to do with the way I'm mounting the share.

I'm starting to exhaust the mount options in trying to resolve this.
I've tried to read the mounted share both as root & regular user. No success.

Tried with the following options:

```
-o uid=33 -gid=33 (to force www-data uid & gid)
-o noperm (no permission check only for server)
-o forceuid (to assign the uid of the owner)
-o credentials=~/credentials (file containing username=devbox password=*** domain=WORKGROUP)
-o rw -o username=devbox -o uid=33 -o gid=33
```

All commands performed successful mount, but still, not able to write!

I really don't understand why this isn't working; it works without issues when mounting from Windows with the OpenVPN Windows client.

Comment: Could you have increase your log level and check the logs? If not configured for it, samba usually doesn't care where the user is coming from.

Comment: FYI, it's really not a good idea to have web server files and dirs **owned** by the same UID that runs the httpd (apache or whatever) as mistakes in your scripts or server config can allow attackers to overwrite your web files (including uploading scripts that attempt to gain root access).  Except for specific directories where you want users to upload files, the httpd only needs  read access to files and read+execute access to dirs.  so files should be owned by someone else (maybe `devbox`), still in group `www-data` with `644` or `640` perms.

Comment: directories should be similar but should also be setgid (so that new files/dirs are created with the same group) as well as executable, so perms would be `2755` or `2750`.  Forgot to mention in last comment, any upload directories should be configured by the server to not execute scripts, CGI or php or whatever.

Comment: Yes youre correct and thanks for the input but this is a dev server container so it doesnt really matter. But i could remove the Force user directive and try that way. But it should work as is. Would like to know why its doesnt.

Comment: It always matters, even on "safe", hidden-behind-the-firewall dev boxes.   BTW, what you're trying should work, without needing to remove the `force user`...i've done it that way many times (in fact, my own vhost setup scripts automate setting up samba shares in this way).  You don't seem to be setting `uid=` or `gid=` or `forceuid`/`forcegid` options for the `mount` command.  are you trying to write to `/mnt` as root or as the user that ran the `sudo` command?   see `man mount.cifs` for details.

Comment: I guess it matters, but time spent redoing is not worth it imo. Yes it should work since it works when mounting from windows, should be no difference. I've mounted with sudo and tried to write both as root user and the user that performed the sudo mount, doesn't work for any of them. Not able to try it out now over OpenVPN but can try experimenting widh uid&guid later today. Thanks alot for your input, if you've got time and want to respond with an answer how to set correct permissions and that whole setup, do so and i will mark it as solved if this isnt some weird bug, which is unlikely.

Comment: the `noperm` mount.cifs option can also be useful.  it tells the linux client not to do permission checks, but to rely on the server to accept or reject access attempts based on the samba username credentials.  read the `mount.cifs` man page carefully before using.

Comment: Almost tried all options available, still not working :)

Comment: when you set `uid=33,gid=33` are you actually writing to the share as user `www-data` (uid 33)?   what do the logs on the samba server say?   what happens if you don't mount it but try to interact with the share with the `smbclient` command-line client (e.g. `smbclient -U devbox '//10.3.10.65/shop'` and try to `put` or `rm` a file)?

Comment: Then i'm mounting the folder as www-data and probably can't write to it because of that. When trying to remove a file with smbclient i get NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED